# Jenkins build fail: fsevents unsupported

Tags: jenkins, npm, build, fsevents

Package-lock.json has fsevents as optionalDependecy, which is causing build to fail. How can I remove it or, make Jenkins support fsevents?

This is what I get from Jenkins when npm install;

```
+ npm install
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding fsevents to package.json as an optional dependency fixed the issue

```
"optionalDependencies": {
   "fsevents": "*"
},
```